# Colliding point of graph in android by using achartEngine in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, achartengine, android-custom-view

In my android application i have developed Graph functionality using aChartEngine android.Every thing fine .I need to draw a circle on the two time series colliding point in graph.Below i show the screen hot of the application.Please help me[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing is sure here: AChartEngine won't provide you APIs for detecting the intersection point between the 2 lines.

If you can compute that yourself then you could add a third series with one single point that would render the intersection point. You will have to set a point style for this series such as you can see it better.

Comment: thanks for reply .....may i know how can i find the insertion point.can you please explain with sample example